# Form values do not update even after binding event handler

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a edit modal that allows a user to update employee information without being re-routed. I have build the modal and inserted it into an employeeCard component (this is the best way I know how to do it, at this point). However, I am unable to change the information in the input fields of the modal, despite writing a handleFieldChange function and trying to reset state on the modalOpen.

I'd like to be able to change the various fields from what was pre-populated in the modal, and on click of the submit button, have the new information compiled into an object and posted to the database.

I've posted only enough code to show the first edit field in the modal, in the interest of saving space and such. The modal is being rendered and pre-populated, but I cannot change anything.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

```
export default class EmployeeCard extends Component {
state = {
    open: false,
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    address: "",
    city: "",
    state: "",
    zip: "",
    image: "",
    hireDate: ""
};

onOpenModal = () => {
    // this.setState({ open: true });
    return userAPImgr.getOneUser(this.props.match.params.employeeId)
        .then(employee => {
            this.setState({
                name: employee.name,
                surname: employee.surname,
                email: employee.email,
                phone: employee.phone,
                address: employee.address,
                city: employee.city,
                state: employee.state,
                zip: employee.zip,
                hireDate: employee.hireDate,
                open: true
            });
        })
    }

            onCloseModal = () => {
                this.setState({ open: false });
            };

            handleFieldChange = evt => {
                const stateToChange = {}
                stateToChange[evt.target.id] = evt.target.value
                this.setState(stateToChange)
            }

            updateEmployee = evt => {
                evt.preventDefault()

                // if (this.state.employee === "") {
                //     window.alert("Please select a caretaker");
                // } else {
                const editedEmployee = {
                    id: parseInt(this.props.match.params.employeeId),
                    name: this.state.name,
                    surname: this.state.surname,
                    email: this.state.email,
                    phone: this.state.phone,
                    address: this.state.address,
                    city: this.state.city,
                    state: this.state.state,
                    zip: this.state.zip,
                    hireDate: this.state.hireDate,
                    companyId: parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("companyId")),
                    userType: "employee"
                };

                this.props.updateUser(editedEmployee, this.props.match.params.employeeId)
                    .then(() => this.props.history.push("/employees"))
            }


            render() {
                const { open } = this.state;
                return (
                    <div key={this.props.employee.id} className="empCard">
                        <div className="empCardBody">
                            <h3 className="empCardTitle">
                                {/* <img src={this.props.employee.image} alt={this.props.employee.name} className="empImg" /> */}
                                <p>{this.props.employee.name} {this.props.employee.surname}</p>
                                <p>{this.props.employee.email}</p>
                                <p>{this.props.employee.phone}</p>
                                <p>{this.props.employee.address}</p>
                                <p>{this.props.employee.city}, {this.props.employee.state} {this.props.employee.zip}</p>

                                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.onOpenModal}>Edit Employee</button>
                                {/* this.props.history.push(`/employees/${this.props.employee.id}/edit`)} >Edit Employee</button> */}
                                <br></br>
                                <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteEmp(this.props.employee.id)}
                                    className="btn btn-danger">Fire Employee
                    </button>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div style={styles}>
                            <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} center>
                                <h2>Edit Employee Info</h2>
                                <form className="employeeForm">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="name">First Name</label>
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            required
                                            className="form-control"
                                            onChange={this.handleFieldChange}
                                            id="name"
                                            placeholder="First Name"
                                            value={this.props.employee.name}
                                        />
                                        <br></br>
```

Comment: at first, the value is null, and then the input is a not binded input... It doesn't change after. Try to use a default for value at input element, like this: value={this.props.employee.name || ''}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there! You need to display the value from state! Check the comments I have added as `//**FIX**:`

```
export default class EmployeeCard extends Component {
state = {
    open: false,
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    address: "",
    city: "",
    state: "",
    zip: "",
    image: "",
    hireDate: ""
};

onOpenModal = () => {
    // this.setState({ open: true });
    return userAPImgr.getOneUser(this.props.match.params.employeeId)
        .then(employee => {
            this.setState({
                name: employee.name,
                surname: employee.surname,
                email: employee.email,
                phone: employee.phone,
                address: employee.address,
                city: employee.city,
                state: employee.state,
                zip: employee.zip,
                hireDate: employee.hireDate,
                open: true
            });
        })
    }

            onCloseModal = () => {
                this.setState({ open: false });
            };

            handleFieldChange = evt => {

                //const stateToChange = {}
                //stateToChange[evt.target.id] = evt.target.value
                //this.setState(stateToChange)
                //**FIX**: you have to include other states that have not changed in the new state

                const updatedState = {
                    ...this.state, // This is called the spread operator
                    [evt.target.id] : evt.target.value
                }
                this.setState(updatedState)

            }

            updateEmployee = evt => {
                evt.preventDefault()

                // if (this.state.employee === "") {
                //     window.alert("Please select a caretaker");
                // } else {
                const editedEmployee = {
                    id: parseInt(this.props.match.params.employeeId),
                    name: this.state.name,
                    surname: this.state.surname,
                    email: this.state.email,
                    phone: this.state.phone,
                    address: this.state.address,
                    city: this.state.city,
                    state: this.state.state,
                    zip: this.state.zip,
                    hireDate: this.state.hireDate,
                    companyId: parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("companyId")),
                    userType: "employee"
                };

                this.props.updateUser(editedEmployee, this.props.match.params.employeeId)
                    .then(() => this.props.history.push("/employees"))
            }


            render() {
                const { open } = this.state;
                return (
                    <div key={this.props.employee.id} className="empCard">
                        <div className="empCardBody">
                            <h3 className="empCardTitle">
                                {/* <img src={this.props.employee.image} alt={this.props.employee.name} className="empImg" /> */}
                                <p>{this.props.employee.name} {this.props.employee.surname}</p>
                                <p>{this.props.employee.email}</p>
                                <p>{this.props.employee.phone}</p>
                                <p>{this.props.employee.address}</p>
                                <p>{this.props.employee.city}, {this.props.employee.state} {this.props.employee.zip}</p>

                                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.onOpenModal}>Edit Employee</button>
                                {/* this.props.history.push(`/employees/${this.props.employee.id}/edit`)} >Edit Employee</button> */}
                                <br></br>
                                <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteEmp(this.props.employee.id)}
                                    className="btn btn-danger">Fire Employee
                    </button>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div style={styles}>
                            <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} center>
                                <h2>Edit Employee Info</h2>
                                <form className="employeeForm">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="name">First Name</label>
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            required
                                            className="form-control"
                                            onChange={this.handleFieldChange}
                                            id="name"
                                            placeholder="First Name"
                                            value={this.state.name}
                                            //**FIX**: show value from state not props
                                        />
                                        <br></br>
```

Comment: Thank you! Though I don't fully understand what you have offered, it is moving me towards having this component fully working as I have hoped. I hope to someday be able to return the favor in kind.

Comment: Keep asking questions! You will get there :)
Also read up here https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html